# How can I use a custom bin to color function with Holoviews HexTiles?

Tags: holoviews

I would like to do HexTiles on values which are 0s and 1s. However, the aggregation should not be a plain mean, but rather something 2-dimensional where the color hue is the mean and the alpha transparency is the standard deviation in the bins.

How can I achieve that with HexTiles?